# iOS Google Maps API drawing overlapping circles

Tags: objective-c, google-maps

I am wondering how to draw two circles using the Google Maps API and, if they overlap each other, if they would get drawn as one shape.

I know how to draw circles, and I know if I drew 2 circles that overlapped that had a solid fill, I would get what I am trying to achieve.

Problem: I want to draw circles that have a transparent fill as well as a solid stroke (border). So if 2 or more circles were to overlap, not only would the stroke overlap but the fill in the overlapping area would be darker.

I would like the border overlap to not be visible as well as the overlapping region to remain the same color/transparency.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map multiple overlay no cumulative opacity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity)

Comment: David, even though the possible duplicate post is in javascript, this seems like a step in the right direction. I will test using the polygon class with the circle class.

Comment: The tag on this question is [google-maps-api-3](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-3/info) which is the Google Maps **Javascript** API v3, if that isn't what you want, fix the tag.