# How to combine circles in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to be able to draw multiple circles on a Google Map with javascript, but combine them as a "single shape" so that their areas don't overlap, but are shared. For example, I found this example at WalkScore.com:

[image]

You can see that they are COMBINING circles, instead of overlapping them as separate shapes.

Is this possible? (Clearly it seems to be, but how?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a Polygon as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity).

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hnrqdpt/) inspired in that solution.

The most important part is combining the circles:

```
var joined = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [drawCircle(smallOne, 150/1609.344, 1),
            drawCircle(bigOne, 300/1609.344, 1)],
            strokeColor: "#ff0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.35,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35
});

joined.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Gotcha - just so i'm getting this right, it's not technically a circle then, right? Or, I should really say, it's a low resolution circle, right? Not that it's wrong, im just curious

Comment: In this case, I would say that the result of joining a bunch of circles in a polygon can be another circle (if one contains the rest), or can be a irregular shape (like in the fiddle or the image you posted), or it also can be a bunch circles if they don't overlap. So technically it is not a circle.

Comment: For those wondering what the 1609.344 is it's 1 mile. So if you want a 15km radius circle you need to do (15 * 1000) / 1609.344

Comment: No, for a 15 km radius it would be just 15 * 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can intersect polygons maybe try topojson.