# How to combine, merge or join circles on Google Maps Api V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

This link [How to combine circles in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26811765/3927450) refer to the same question but not on Android.
So, how can I merge circles like that?

I have 10 markers with its respective circles around them, when the user zoom out it looks fine, but if zoom in, the circles overlapping each other, so, the fill shade of the circle get darker and darker. I want the same shade inside the intersection of the circles or merge the circles.
I want the entire map with shade but the circle clear. So I try using a polygon with shade over the entire map and add circle holes for each marker, but with 6 or more marker doesnt work.

Thank guys...

Comment: Did you found an solution ?