# Combine circles as polygon without intersecting common areas

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a coverage map for my company's vendors, and then need to check how many of our customers live outside the overall coverage.  A vendor's coverage area is always a circle.

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811765/how-to-combine-circles-in-google-maps) solution to combine the coverage areas of our vendors into a single polygon so that I can use the [containsLocation function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#poly) to compare out customer's locations.  The problem is that the containsLocation function identifies some overlapping coverage areas as being outside coverage. Here is an example, where the pin should remain invisible because it is within the coverage of 2 vendors.
[Overlapping Vendor Coverage Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e92RO.png)

```
  function updateMap(){
     var radius = $('#radius').val();
     $.ajax({
       url: "",
       dataType: "json",
       type: "POST",
       data: $('#dataForm').serialize()
     }).done(function(result){
       for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
         center = {lat: parseFloat(result[i].Latitude), lng: parseFloat(result[i].Longitude)};
         shapeArray.push(drawCircle(center, (radius), 1));
       }
        coverage = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: shapeArray,
            strokeColor: "#ff0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: "#ff0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map
        });
     });
  }

  function drawCircle(point, radius, dir)
  { 
    var d2r = Math.PI / 180;   // degrees to radians 
    var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;   // radians to degrees 
    var earthsradius = 3963; // 3963 is the radius of the earth in miles
    var points = 32; 

    // find the raidus in lat/lon 
    var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d; 
    var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat * d2r); 

    var extp = new Array(); 
    if (dir==1) {var start=0;var end=points+1} // one extra here makes sure we connect the
    else{var start=points+1;var end=0}
    for (var i=start; (dir==1 ? i < end : i > end); i=i+dir)  
    {
        var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points/2)); 
        ey = point.lng + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
        ex = point.lat + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
        extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey));
    }
    return extp;
  } 

  function showUncovered(el){
    if(!el.checked){
      for(var i=0; i<markerArray.length; i++){
          markerArray[i].setVisible(false);
      }
      return;
    }
    for(var i=0;i<markerArray.length;i++){
      var pos = markerArray[i].position;
      var isAffected = false;
      if(!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pos,coverage)){
        markerArray[i].setVisible(true);
      }       
    }         
  }
```

Comment: You say " the pin should remain invisible" but your code is basically saying `if containsLocation() { setVisible(true) }`  - shouldn't it be the other way around? `markerArray[i].setVisible(false);` to hide it

Comment: My apologies. The map will eventually need to be able to flip back and forth between pins inside and outside the coverage area and I must have copy/pasted my code incorrectly for the case I was stating.  The code has been updated.

Comment: Here is a fiddle I forked from the noted example that puts the value of containsLocation in the console.  Note that when clicking where the polygon circles intersect it will return false. http://jsfiddle.net/qrvvctja/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google accepted this as a bug.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10609

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the circles you can iterate `shapeArray` and run `.containsLocation(...` in each circle, the first that contains the location ends the loop (if not, the marker is outside the polygon).

Actually, this is the solution proposed in the filed [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10609) (and looks like they won't fix it).