# Android Google Map: how to combine multiple overlays together

Tags: android, google-maps, android-activity

In my project, I have to show more than 3000 overlays on the map, each of them got a unique position, which causes the program too laggy.. I guess the problem would be my program has to update or refresh the shape of each overlay individually for the screen. My idea is to combine the 3000 overlays together into one, but I still don't really know how to make it out.

Could anybody give me any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use '*Polygon*', A '*Polygon*' is like a poly-line. A series of connected coordinates in an ordered sequence, It also form a closed loop and define a filled region.

For more information, please view Official Google Documentation for Combining and visualising multiple data sources: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/combining-data

Also, Here's a related Stack overflow ticket, it might help you: [Google map multiple overlay no cumulative opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity)