# Android google map markers circles (multiple overlay no cumulative opacity)

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, marker

i am trying to add multiple markers, which in some  situations can appear near to each others. I am trying to add circle around them 
code of adding circles

```
points.forEach { point ->
        googleMap.addCircle(
            CircleOptions()
                .center(point.location)
                .radius(10.toDouble())
                .strokeWidth(1f)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .fillColor(Color.argb(60, 255, 0, 0))
        )
    }
```

LEFT : is what i get with my code ______________ RIGHT : this is what i need
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSD1A.png
Is it even possible in android ?

Comment: Did you try `zIndex`? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CircleOptions.html#zIndex(float)

Comment: I dont think i t is possible to solve my problem by z-index. My problem is opacity of the overlaying parts (as you can see in the picture)

Comment: I know the below question is in another language but hope this help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity

Comment: polygone is different in android maps

Comment: @ToraCode the android sdk polygon does not have the strokeOpacity function.

Comment: With `addCircle()`? Probably not. If I were you I'd hack something together using a `GroundOverlay`. That is, prepare a `Bitmap` in advance that's composed the way you want, and use it to cover the whole map.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting zindex to 1:

```
final CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions();
options.center(new LatLng(geofence.getCenter().getLatitude(), geofence.getCenter().getLongitude()));
options.radius(geofence.maxDistance().getValue());
options.strokeColor(Color.RED);
options.strokePattern(Collections.singletonList(new Dot()));
options.zIndex(1f);

geofenceCircle = googleMap.addCircle(options);
```

I have my own tile provider and for some reason zindex of 0 didn't work.

According to Google:

> Z-Index The order in which this tile overlay is drawn with respect to
>   other overlays (including GroundOverlays, TileOverlays, Polylines, and
>   Polygons but not Markers). An overlay with a larger z-index is drawn
>   over overlays with smaller z-indices. The order of overlays with the
>   same z-index is arbitrary. The default zIndex is 0.