# Is there a function to merge multiple overlapped MAUI Map elements?

Tags: maps, maui

i have multiple map elements in my MAUI Map project and i'm very unhappy about the overlapped area.

I can't find any simple solution out there. Maybe someone can help me here out. Anyone have an idea how i can merge the two circle so the overlapped area did not looks darker?

[image]

A very hard and painful method that I do not prefer is to convert the two circles to a polygon.

Thanks!

Here is my code example:

```
var circle = new Circle
{
    Center = new Location(48.9624, 10.1295), // Koordinaten für das Zentrum des Kreises (z.B. Berlin)
    Radius = new Distance(100), // Radius in Metern
    StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000"), // Farbe des Kreisrandes
    StrokeWidth = 1, // Dicke des Kreisrandes
    FillColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000"),// Füllfarbe des Kreises (Rot mit etwas Transparenz)
};

var circle1 = new Circle
{
    Center = new Location(48.9619, 10.1315), // Koordinaten für das Zentrum des Kreises (z.B. Berlin)
    Radius = new Distance(100), // Radius in Metern
    StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000"), // Farbe des Kreisrandes
    StrokeWidth = 1, // Dicke des Kreisrandes
    FillColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000") // Füllfarbe des Kreises (Rot mit etwas Transparenz),
};

map.MapElements.Add(circle);
map.MapElements.Add(circle1);
```

**EDIT 1:**

I tried it with a polygon like follow. Now i get a line across the two circle. The Fill Color also did not show.

```
var points = GeographyUtils.ToCircumferencePositions(circle);
points.AddRange(GeographyUtils.ToCircumferencePositions(circle1));

var polygon= new Polygon
{
    StrokeColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000"),
    StrokeWidth = 5, // Dicke des Kreisrandes
    FillColor = Color.FromArgb("50FF0000"),
};

foreach (var location in points)
{
    polyline.Geopath.Add(location);
}

map.MapElements.Add(polygon);
```

[image]

Comment: Do you only want to achieve this effect on iOS device?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT Sorry, i would like to achieve this effect on both platforms IOS and Android if possible

Comment: [How do I color code areas on maps?](https://support.google.com/maps/thread/14273465/how-do-i-color-code-areas-on-maps-i-want-to-outline-neighborhoods-with-different-colors?hl=en) This link indicates that your demand is difficult to achieve. You can ask for more details on [Google Maps Community](https://support.google.com/maps/community?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a polygon something like this [Google map multiple overlay no cumulative opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154254/google-map-multiple-overlay-no-cumulative-opacity)

Also could look at mapsui library

Comment: I tried this also, i'm very thankful when you can take a second look on my Edit 1. Yes i think with the mapsui library it will work but i did not like the map look very

Comment: In the answer's link, it is recommended to draw one polygon with multiple paths.